# Creating user with default group django rest framework viewsets

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

how do I create user with default group? my serializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')

def create(self, validated_data):
    user = super(UserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
    user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
    user.save()
    return user
```

**views.py**

```
class UserView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = User.objects.all()
   serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

How do I set user group when creating from this view?

Answer (score 1):

Just add something like

```
user.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='Whatever'))
```

after `user.save()` in the `create` method.